# Photon Pun 2 (no suitable method found to override)

Tags: c#

no suitable method found to override
Hello i am a begginer in C# and i am not able to overide void the following code can some one pls help me this is my error

Assets\GameData\Script\PhotonLauncherScript.cs(15,26): error CS0115: 'PhotonLauncherScript.OnConnectedToMaster()': no suitable method found to override

Assets\GameData\Script\PhotonLauncherScript.cs(20,27): error CS0115: 'PhotonLauncherScript.OnJoinedLobby()': no suitable method found to override

here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PhotonLauncherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Connecting to Master");
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    Debug.Log("Connected to Master");
    PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
}
public  override void OnJoinedLobby()
{
    Debug.Log("Joined Lobby succesfully");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I could identify 2 Errors, that may have caused your problem.

1.) You need to use Photon.Realtime as well as Photon.Pun in your Script. So add "using Photon.Realtime;" on top.

2.) OnConnectedToMaster is an override for MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks.OnConnectedToMaster(), whilst there is no similar Function in MonoBehaviour. That's what the Console Error Log shows you  - so edit your class Definition to: public class PhotonLauncherScript : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks

Wish you the best!

P.S.:
For further information you may take a look at the official Pun2 Tutorial at: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/lobby - It was very helpful for myself on a similar topic, for it covers the basics of setting up a PUN or PUN2 multiplayer App using C# and Unity.